# is there easy way to handle UIAlertView result without delegation?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a function that shows a UIAlertView with YES/NO buttons, and it is used only inside the function's scope so I dont want to implement a delegation to catch the user feedback.

Is there any way to know what button users clicked without implement UIAlertViewDelegate, something like:

```
[alert show];
if([alert indexOfClickedButton] == indexOfYes)
{
....
}
```

Or lambda expression as in Animation

Comment: UIALertview without delegation there is only one way that u create a custom UIALertview.

Comment: Here is a site that implements a block-based UIAlertview (along with other things):  http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-block-based-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet/

Comment: UIAlertView *aletView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Any Title" message:@"Hiii" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
don't use any delegate if you want.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no way to avoid delegation completely, but you could create a wrapper to that effect along these lines:

```
@interface MyAlertViewDelegate : NSObject<UIAlertViewDelegate>

typedef void (^AlertViewCompletionBlock)(NSInteger buttonIndex);
@property (strong,nonatomic) AlertViewCompletionBlock callback;

+ (void)showAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView withCallback:(AlertViewCompletionBlock)callback;

@end


@implementation MyAlertViewDelegate
@synthesize callback;

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    callback(buttonIndex);
}

+ (void)showAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
         withCallback:(AlertViewCompletionBlock)callback {
    __block MyAlertViewDelegate *delegate = [[MyAlertViewDelegate alloc] init];
    alertView.delegate = delegate;
    delegate.callback = ^(NSInteger buttonIndex) {
        callback(buttonIndex);
        alertView.delegate = nil;
        delegate = nil;
    };
    [alertView show];
}

@end
```

(ARC is assumed, if you are not using it change `delegate = nil` to `[delegate release]`.)

Usage would be something like:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm" message:@"Yes or No?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"No", nil];
[MyAlertViewDelegate showAlertView:alert withCallback:^(NSInteger buttonIndex) {
    // code to take action depending on the value of buttonIndex
}];
```

Comment: I'm getting a compiler warning on the line where you do `delegate = nil` saying : Capturing delegate strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle. This under iOS 5.1 ARC.

Comment: `delegate = nil` is necessary because `alertView.delegate` is a non-retaining property and we need to keep the object "delegate" until the alert view is button callback is finished. The warning (a false positive) can be ignored with `#pragma clang diagnostic push` and `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-retain-cycles"` before, and `#pragma clang diagnostic pop` after that line.

Comment: Great, thank! You can just pass `delegate:nil` when creating the alert.

Comment: 2015 update: `UIAlertView` is deprecated and its replacement, `UIAlertController`, allows adding actions with `UIAlertAction`, which takes a block as action handler.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a blog post about how to (and why) add block callbacks to alert views, action sheets and animations:

http://blog.innovattic.com/uikitblocks/

If you just want a working implementation of this you can download the sources files from GitHub:

https://github.com/Innovattic/UIKit-Blocks

Usage:

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My easy alert"  
                                                message:@"Would you like to perform some kind of action?"
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alert setHandler:^(UIAlertView* alert, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
    NSLog(@"Perform some kind of action");
} forButtonAtIndex:[alert firstOtherButtonIndex]];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy. Say you have an alert, something like this:

```
//Alert
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm" message:@"Yes or No?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"No", nil];
[alert show];
```

You're going to need to add this method:

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

A possible implementation of this method would look like this:

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

//Checks For Approval
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        //do something because they selected button one, yes
    } else {
        //do nothing because they selected no
    }
}
```

Comment: But he specifically asked how to do it _without delegation_…

Comment: Thank! And yes, it will save me some line of codes, but i still have to write some code outside of the function's scope and, probably, save a reference of the alertview, that is what I dont want. I'm looking for a block-based solution, and if there is no simple way to do that, I think your solution would be the best.

Comment: Glad I was able to help out some!

Comment: @jAckOdE if you do not want to keep a reference for alert view object, you can use tags for alert view. example, alert = 101; and in - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex, you can check , if alert.tag == 101 {}....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using custom view which can be hidden and shown to avoid ActionSheets

```
UIView *AlertVw=[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRect(x,y,w,h)]];

UIButton *SaveButton=[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRect(x,y,w,h)]];
[CustomButton setTitle:@"Ok" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[SaveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(SaveClicked)            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *CancelButton=[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRect(x,y,w,h)]];
[CustomButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[CancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(CancelClicked)            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[AlertVw addSubview:SaveButton];
[AlertVw addSubview:CancelButton];

[self.view addSubview:AlertVw];

-(void)SaveButton
 {
   //Code to apply on Save clicked
  [AlertVw removeFromSuperView];  //Also you can use AlertView.hidden=YES;

 }
-(void)CancelButton
 {
   //Code to apply on cancel clicked
  [AlertVw removeFromSuperView];  //Also you can use AlertView.hidden=YES;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to derive the class. With Block, it is easy to get user selected button index.

```
typedef void(^AlertViewCallBackBlock)(NSInteger selectedIndex);

@interface ABC ()
    @property (nonatomic, copy) AlertViewCallBackBlock alertViewBlock;
@end

@implementation

- (void)showAlert {
    self.alertViewBlock = ^(NSInteger selectedIndex) {
        if (selectedIndex == 1) {

        }
    };
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm" message:@"Yes or No?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"No", nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    self.alertViewBlock(buttonIndex);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Arkku**. Here is the Swift version.

https://github.com/exchangegroup/alert-view-with-callback-swift

```
let alertView = UIAlertView(...)

AlertViewWithCallback().show(alertView) { alertView, buttonIndex in
  println("You closed alert by tapping button #\(buttonIndex)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertView` is deprecated from iOS 8.0, a better solution will be using `UIAlertController`:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "message", message: "Title", preferredStyle: .Alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    // Action for YES
}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    // Action for NO
}))

self.view.window!.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```